# only can write until the 924th byte using RandomAccessFile

Tags: java

Im having a problem when i try to fill up a randomaccessfile, in using a loop for it and it stops writing when it reaches de 924th byte, so when i try to fill up 2500 bytes with "-" for example, it only fills 924 byte. Here is the code that im using, hope someone can tell me what i am doing wrong

```
public class Hashing {
    private RandomAccessFile espacio;

    public Hashing() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        File amigos = new File("Texto");
        String r = "rws";
        espacio = new RandomAccessFile(amigos ,r);
        this.estableceEspacioLlenado();
    }

    public void estableceEspacioLlenado() throws IOException{
        int a = 0;

        while(a<2500){
            if(a>=241 && a%241==0){
                espacio.writeBytes("\n"); 
                a++;
            }
            else{
                espacio.writeBytes("-");
                a++;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

output file:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I lowercased your variables and methods to follow Java naming conventions. Only class names should be capitalized.

Comment: Why are you using a RandomAccessFile, especially when writing text? Why not simply use a BufferedWriter that holds a FileWriter?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. Verifying with `ls -al Texto.txt` shows the size of the generated file: `-rw-r--r--  1 tekperigin  staff  2500 Nov 27 23:56 Texto.txt`

Comment: because the purpose of filling up the that file, is to make a hashing data structure and i need to get random access to any position of the file so i can store the data i want to store wherever i want .

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the data is buffered and hasn't been flushed to disk. Add a `close()` call at the end to ensure everything gets written.

```
espacio = new RandomAccessFile(amigos ,r);
this.estableceEspacioLlenado();
espacio.close();
```